# C# Reducing the Network bandwith usage

Tags: c#, sockets, image-processing, compression

**I'll give a small introduction**: I work on  a small screen sharing project in c# and i use the `Tcp Protocol` for sending the data. Basically i call the `BitBlt` method  from the GDI and it does the work very well. In the first time i send the entire buffer,and then i iterate and send only the changed pixels.
each byte in the buffer i send represent a component (in the **Rgba** order)-  this is a small array for a short example:

```
byte[] pixelarray = { 45, 201, 173,1 };
//R=45,G=201,B=173,Alpha=1(always 1 on screen).
```

Lets move on.
My screen is 1920x1080(in my case) so actually **1920x1080x4**(each pixel is 4 bytes)**= up to 8,294,400 Pixels.**
Using  `Gzipstream`compressiong on this reduce  the size to ~250kb. This is what i send in the first time.After that, i simply compare the byte arrays of each `BitBlt` capture and send only the pixel which changed. It looks somthing like that:

```
public void StartAsync(ScreenFrame frame)
    {
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {       
           for (var i = 0; i < frame.NewPixels.Length; i += 4)
           {
                    memoryStream.WriteByte(frame.NewPixels[i]);
                    memoryStream.WriteByte(frame.NewPixels[i + 1]);
                    memoryStream.WriteByte(frame.NewPixels[i + 2]);          
            }

            byte[] data = compress(memoryStream.ToArray());//compress gzip.
           SendVarData(data);//this is a simple function to send it on a socket.

        }
    }


    public void DeltaAsync(ScreenFrame frame) 
    { 
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        { 
            for (var i = 0; i < frame.NewPixels.Length; i += 4)//loop through buffers and write only differnt bytes.
        {
            if (frame.NewPixels[i] == frame.PreviousPixels[i] &&
                frame.NewPixels[i + 1] == frame.PreviousPixels[i + 1] &&
                frame.NewPixels[i + 2] == frame.PreviousPixels[i + 2])
                continue;
            memoryStream.Write(BitConverter.GetBytes(i), 0, 4);//write the index.
            memoryStream.WriteByte(frame.NewPixels[i]);
            memoryStream.WriteByte(frame.NewPixels[i + 1]);
            memoryStream.WriteByte(frame.NewPixels[i + 2]);
            }
            byte[] buff = compress(memoryStream.ToArray());//compress gzip.
            SendVarData(buff);
        }
    }
```

Processing and applying the changes in the other side isnt my main problem.
My real bottleneck is the **bandwith usage**. At a small change on the desktop,for  example when user use the right click in his mouse and open the classic menu, the data which sent is (**after compression!**) around 120~150kb!
I would realy like to optimize it.. i cant let my program to send huge data over the network when there's only a small change...
As you see i already use

- A gzip compression(which offers a high compression ratio).
- Writing only the differences.

  Im looking for ways to optimize the network idea... i would very very appreicate any incoming help since im breaking my head pretty long time and trying to think about somthing can help...

Thanks.

Comment: Sounds a lot like a simple RFB implementation, have you looked at existing open source VNC clients?

Comment: One thing you could do is "try" to detect contiguous colour blocks and send "200x100 Grey Rectangle" which you could in a few bytes instead of 60k (before compression)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changes to the screen will often affect all (or most) of the bytes in rectangular blocks.  Your compression is inefficient (compared to other remote viewer apps) because it does not take this into account.  One approach is to try to identify the bounds of regions that have changed, and then sending the entire region compressed with something like png.  But really you should study the kind of transforms png and other image-compression algorithms perform on 2d data to make them more compressible.

Transforms are reversible manipulations to the image data that are applied before the data compression step that are designed to make data more compressible.  One transform might be to subtract the pixel value from the pixel in the row above.  If the image hasn't changed much from one row to the next, you will get a lot of zeros from this, which will be more compressible than the actual pixel data for each row.

Comment: okay.. thanks.. but what do you mean compressed with somthing like png? :)

Comment: @Slashy -- Create a bitmap that represents the changed portion of the image, and save it to a stream as a .png (or as a .jpg if you can live with compression artifacts)-- that's a naive approach.  Suggestion in the comments on the question to look at source code for VNC implementations is also good.

Comment: i'll look into vnc..(first i should fine a link of it haha. this is my first times with that). about your idea, it's similar to what i do.. crop it from the image and save to a memorystream as png is what i do... do you know how png is stored? it's a rgba byte array compreesed with gzip... so i dont see any reason to do this...(Without mentioning the complexibilty of finding the different areas and send each time the areas(can be some different areas on one image)).

Comment: @Slashy -- see expanded answer

Comment: thanks for you explnation man, i realy appreicate it, but i dont think i got you 100% about the transofrm technique. if i'll cess the pixel value from one row... then from the second.. what should i do then..? im little confused :)

Comment: This link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics#Compression explains the transforms (described there as filters) used by .png.  The concept is common to image compression.  But there are compression techniques specifically for remote frame-buffer applications, which are better and which you will find in the VNC source code.